# Can I prevent just myself pushing `develop`?

Tags: git

Our `git` repo (hosted by github) does not protect against pushes to the `develop` branch. We could turn this on but the team would prefer not to.

Can I set up my personal *local* tooling to prevent me from mistakenly pushing local changes to `develop`?

Alternatively, is there a setting such that to push to `develop`, I need to:

```
git push --yes-i-really-mean-it
```

Comment: You can write a Git hook for the [`pre-push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) event.

Comment: You can use a (client side) `pre-push hook`. "The pre-push hook runs during git push, after the remote refs have been updated but before any objects have been transferred. " See [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Comment: If I use a pre-push hook, wouldn’t it be  part of the repo ad this also inpact all other users?

Comment: But why don't use push to a branch called `develop`?

Comment: No, all git hooks are local and are not added to the repo.

Comment: @evolutionxbox – excellent, thanks. I'll look in to this.